# Using Arabic letters in Django urls causes a 404 error

Tags: python, django

I want to use Arabic letters in my addresses, there is no problem in local mode, but it causes an error on the server.

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='عنوان محصول')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True,allow_unicode=True, verbose_name='آدرس')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('detail/<str:slug>', ProductDetail.as_view(), name='product_detail')
]
```

views.py

```
class ProductDetail(DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product_app/product_detail.html'
```

Comment: Provide detailed error

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `mysql` as your db backend , you have to add utf8 unicode

```
create database mysite character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```